# Using conda to install PyTorch within a Visual Studio python project

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, pytorch

I've created a Python project within Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

I've changed the environment within the Visual Studio Python project to be Anaconda 5.2.

If I just use the "Install Python Package..." menu in Visual Studio and type PyTorch, it's says the package is not found.

So, I thought next I should just run this command...

```
conda install pytorch -c pytorch
```

If I open the Python Environments within Visual Studio, click on Anaconda 5.2, and click Open in Powershell, and execute the command above in the Powershell terminal, it eventually fails because of a permission error.  Guessing this is due to not having Administrative Privileges.

If I just open the Run menu in Windows and open a Powershell with Administrative Privileges then "conda" is not found typing the command above.

How should I be installing PyTorch in the Visual Studio Anaconda environment?